Interpreting The Gradle Compatibility Matrix (Java) for Android Development
On the Gradle Compatibility Matrix for Java Runtime, there is only one single Java version associated with a given Gradle Wrapper version (I'm assuming "Grade Version" can mean "Gradle Wrapper Version").
So... does that mean that there is only a single Java version that is compatible with a given Gradle version?   That seems ridiculous and I would expect that it means "maximum compatible Java version" and that a given Gradle version is backwards compatible with older Java versions to some extent.
If it is true that only one version of Java will work (or is guaranteed to work), how are developers expected to work on more than one project if those projects vary in their Gradle wrapper versions (since they all rely on the system installed (singular) Java version)?
So what is the meaning of this single Java version stated on the matrix?
Is it:

A) Minimum required version
B) Maximum required version
C) Exact required version
D) Something else

If there is actually a range of Java versions compatible with a given Gradle version, then why is that not reflected in the compatibility matrix?

"since they all rely on the system installed (singular) Java version" -- it is unclear how you came to that conclusion, or perhaps I am misunderstanding it. The point behind the Gradle Wrapper is to not be reliant on any existing Gradle installation. The version of Gradle identified in gradle-wrapper.properties is the one that is used.

I was referring to Java installation ie. what JAVA_HOME points to.

My apologies! I see where I went wrong. To your main question: I worry about Gradle and Java versions when Gradle complains, and that's about it. That page that you link to is poorly written.

Read the first two paragraphs at Java Runtime carefully:

A JVM version between 8 and 23 is required to execute Gradle. JVM 24 and later versions are not yet supported.
Executing the Gradle daemon with JVM 16 or earlier has been deprecated and will become an error in Gradle 9.0. The Gradle wrapper, Gradle client, Tooling API client, and TestKit client will remain compatible with JVM 8.
[...]
Any fully supported version of Java can be used for compilation or testing. However, the latest Java version may only be supported for compilation or testing, not for running Gradle. Support is achieved using toolchains and applies to all tasks supporting toolchains.

That means that you should read entries like




Java Version
Support for toolchains
Support for running Gradle




20
8.1
8.3


21
8.4
8.5




as follows:

you can use Gradle version 8.4 to compile and test code for Java 21
you cannot use Java 21 to run Gradle version 8.4. To run Gradle 8.4, you need an earlier version of Java (from Java 8 to Java 20 since you can use those versions to run Gradle 8.3 and later)
if you want Java 21 to run Gradle you must use Gradle 8.5 or later

